# Вывод элементов из инифоблока Битрикс api

Tags: битрикс

Например ,есть инфоблок Настройки , внутри инфоблока настройки есть поля одна ссылка, другая фото. Нужно через API выводить на страницу эти поля. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

Если это контентная область страницы то там ни какого `API` не должно быть, например `news.detail` там можно выбрать нужные поля и свойства и вывести их в шаблоне, только шаблон компонента нужно скопировать в свой шаблон сайта и там менять подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/)

 Если нужно через `API` тогда так:
`CModule::IncludeModule('iblock'); // подключаем модуль инфоблоков
$arSelect = Array('NAME', 'PROPERTY_LINK'); // тут поля которые нужны вытащить свойства все начинаются с PROPERTY_ и код свойства
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => 2, "ID" => 12);//фильтр по id инфоблока и id элемента инфоблока
$dbResult = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(1), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect); // делаем запрос через API битиркса
while($arResult = $dbResult->Fetch()){ // тут мы по циклу получаем из объекта выборки элементы инфоблока
    echo "<pre>".print_r($arResult, true)."</pre>";// выводим результат выборки
}`

Comment: <pre>($arResult)</pre>

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("");
// get parent sections list
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock'); // подключаем модуль инфоблоков
$arSelect = Array('NAME', 'PROPERTY_81'); // тут поля которые нужны вытащить свойства все начинаются с PROPERTY_ и код свойства
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => 20, "ID" => 81);//фильтр по id инфоблока и id элемента инфоблока
$dbResult = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(1), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect); // делаем запрос через API битиркса
while($arResult = $dbResult->Fetch()){ // тут мы по циклу получаем из объекта выборки элементы инфоблока
echo "<pre>".print_r($arResult, true)."</pre>";// выводим результат выборки
}
?>

<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: вот так сделал , но не получилось

Comment: можете обяснить ? правильно ли я делаю... и один пример покажите как поставить на ссылку <img>